# How to make Gmail or Facebook like scroll bar without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, scroll

We have seen many example or source code in internet to make scroll bar like Gmail/Facebook, using Jquery. But i am looking for some light weight javascript to make the scrollbar thin like in Gmail. 
Please someone share more information.

Answer (score 4):

In **webkit** you can do this in **Css**.
This will be lighter than any javascript code.
Learn  more about Css custom scrollbars:
 
http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/
In other browsers, I would suggest you to stay with the native scrollbars.
Custom scrollbars in javascript are, most of the time, not that a great add-on after-thought.